# Spring Security Авторизация с помощью JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, auth, spring-security

Объясните (желательно, с примерами кода), как реализовать авторизацию пользователя с помощью JSON, а именно:

Есть сущность:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8647833898589302685L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name= "increment", strategy= "increment")
    @Column(name = "id_user", nullable = false)
    private int idUser;

    @Column(name = "login", length = 15, nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password", length = 32, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    protected User() {}
}
```

К ней, репозиторий:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    User findUserByLogin(String login);
}
```

И имеется контроллер:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,
                    value = "/login",
                    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
                    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public HttpEntity<User> login(@RequestBody User user) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,
                    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public HttpEntity<List<User>> findAllUser() {
        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        if (users != null && !users.isEmpty())
            return new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,
                    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE,
                    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public HttpEntity<User> saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        User newUser = userService.saveUser(user);
        if (newUser != null)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(newUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED);
    }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтоб авторизация проходила по ссылке `POST /users/login`, передав JSON класса User, а выход из аккаунта соответственно по ссылке `POST /users/logout` также метода в UserController?

Comment: Это работает не так. Вам надо переопределить Filter и Authentication Provider. И встроить туда свою логику. В контроллерах не должно быть никакой логики логина-логаута.

Comment: как тогда сделать авторизацию, без страницы авторизации, для Android приложения например?

Comment: У SpringSecurity есть адрес который он прослушивает на запросы авторизации, на него и надо отправлять запрос, вот только это всё на веб рассчитано, насколько знаю, в андройде необходимо применять другие подходы(т.е. вообще не SpringSecurity).